# Find Median from Data Stream __init__ in Class issue

Tags: python, list, containers, global-variables, heap

I have a question on defining the **init** in class. The original problem is:

> Design a class to calculate the median of a number stream. The class
> should have the following two methods:
>
> insertNum(int num): stores the number in the class findMedian():
> returns the median of all numbers inserted in the class If the count
> of numbers inserted in the class is even, the median will be the
> average of the middle two numbers.

My original code is:

```
from heapq import *


class Solution:
    # define the min and max heaps
    def __init__(self):
        self.minHeap = []
        self.maxHeap = []

    def insertNum(self, num):
        # check if the first number into the heap
        # use -num to create the max heap
        if not self.maxHeap or num <= -self.maxHeap[0]:
            heappush(self.maxHeap, -num)
        else:
            heappush(self.minHeap, num)
        print(self.minHeap, self.maxHeap)
        # ensure l(maxHeap) = l(minHeap) or +1
        # 4 vs 2
        if len(self.maxHeap) > len(self.minHeap) + 1:
            heappush(self.minHeap, -heappop(self.maxHeap))
        # 1 vs 2
        elif len(self.maxHeap) < len(self.minHeap):
            heappush(self.maxHeap, -heappop(self.minHeap))
        print(self.minHeap, self.maxHeap)

    def findMedian(self):
        print(self.minHeap, self.maxHeap)
        if len(self.minHeap) == len(self.maxHeap):
            return 0.5 * (self.minHeap[0] - self.maxHeap[0])
        if len(self.maxHeap) == len(self.minHeap) + 1:
            return -self.maxHeap[0]


def main():
    Solution().insertNum(3)
    Solution().insertNum(1)
    print("The median is: " + str(Solution().findMedian()))
    Solution().insertNum(5)
    print("The median is: " + str(Solution().findMedian()))
    Solution().insertNum(4)
    print("The median is: " + str(Solution().findMedian()))


main()
```

And it will return the following output:

```
[] [-3]
[] [-3]
[] [-1]
[] [-1]
[] []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tairanye/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/tairanye/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 38, in main
    print("The median is: " + str(Solution().findMedian()))
  File "/Users/tairanye/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 30, in findMedian
    return 0.5 * (self.minHeap[0] - self.maxHeap[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think the main issue here is that `minHeap` and `maxHeap` reset each time I call `insertNumber`. Once I updated the initial line of codes as following, the issue will go.

```
class Solution:
    # define the min and max heaps

    minHeap = []
    maxHeap = []

    def insertNum(self, num):
```

I am not sure the reason behind this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because you keep constructing a new object, `Solution().insertNum(3)`. So of course `__init__` keeps getting called. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Your update, btw, would throw a `NameError`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Thanks for your help. I tried to create a container, or heap table, to sort the elements. Does it mean that each time I call the `insertNumber()`, the `__init__` will ignore the previous heap table, and create an empty one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your help. I already remove `self.` in my update.

Comment: No, it'd each time you call `Solution()`, that *instantiates a `Solution` object. You create a new container each time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class definition seems to be alright. But it is wrong with the usage of `Solution()` in your main function. `Solution` is a class type, every time when you call `Solution()`, it creates a new object/instance. Even though you have already run

```
Solution().insertNum(3)
Solution().insertNum(1)
```

before

```
print("The median is: " + str(Solution().findMedian()))
```

However `Solution()` in the last line of code has no data stored. They are very different objects (or the latter has rewritten the previous objects). Because calling `Solution()` creates another object every time, which is obvious that the error message is complaing that there is no data in `self.minHeap`, thus invoking `self.minHeap[0]` would cause `IndexError: list index out of range` error.
Hopefully, by far why this error message is clear to you.

Now let's talk about why the following code would work fine.

```
class Solution:
    # define the min and max heaps

    minHeap = []
    maxHeap = []

    def insertNum(self, num):
```

Now you have defined

```
minHeap = []
maxHeap = []
```

as class variable rather than instance variable (defined with `self`). Thus when you call `Solution()` every time,even a new instance has been created, but the data would be stored as class variable and they will live with class untill the class is destroyed.

The following two lines of code stored the data into the class, rather than the instance created by `Solution()`

```
Solution().insertNum(3)
Solution().insertNum(1)
```

That 's why later when you run

```
print("The median is: " + str(Solution().findMedian()))
```

there is no error, because a new instance created by `Solution()` has the data already when it was created.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alberta. Does it mean that the class variable is a global variable, and it won't go with another call of this class. However, the instance variable only lives with current class.

Comment: I highly recommend you to get more in-depth knowledge of the class variable vs instance variable in python. Class variable is not a global variable, because it only lives within the class.  But any instance created later will have these variables. If you like my answer above, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do you have any recommendation to read?